# Jupyter lab doesn't work in Colab after successful SSH access and python3 upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I tried to launch Jupyter lab on Colab after successful SSH access. I got the following error message and wondering about any resolution.

```
[C 20:26:25.325 LabApp] The 'contents_manager_class' trait of <jupyterlab.labapp.LabApp object at 0x7f5cc9c73fd0> instance must be a type, but 'google.colab._contents_manager.ColabFileContentsManager' could not be imported
```

The `/jupyter_notebook_config.py` configuration file in my `/root/.jupyter` folder is edited as follows:

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
c.NotebookApp.token = ''
c.NotebookApp.contents_manager_class = "jupytext.TextFileContentsManager"
```

The last line is simply for the use of the Jupyter extension `jupytext`.

I don't know why I got this error message today after I upgraded the Colab default Python 3.6 to Python 3.7. The same Jupyter setup workflow always works for me but today.

Here is the list of command I typed in the command line after connecting my local machine to Colab.

```
# upgrade to python 3.7
sudo apt-get install python3.7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3 
# Then I chose the option for "/usr/bin/python3.7 2 manual mode"

# To fix missing pip when issue pip3 command
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip

# To install packages including jupyterlab
sudo pip3 install scipy==1.4.1 
sudo pip3 install numpy matplotlib pandas seaborn scikit-learn tensorflow keras jupyterlab
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I installed Python 3.7 on Colab but forgot to install package google-colab. This is a quick answer to resolve this issue.